# Screen height - Android

Tags: android, navigationbar, screen-size

In an Android Application, I want to know the height and the width of the screen. I'm using the following code:

```
 Point size = new Point();
 display.getSize(size);
 screenWidth = size.x;
 screenHeight = size.y;
```

The problem is than when the soft navigation bar exists, the returned height = the actual height - navigation bar height.
I want to get the total value.

Note: I'm using Android SDK 13 (v 3.2).

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it may help:

```
FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    root.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            Window win = getWindow();  // Get the Window
            win.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            // Get the height of Status Bar
            int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
            // Get the height occupied by the decoration contents
            int contentViewTop = win.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
            // Calculate titleBarHeight by deducting statusBarHeight from contentViewTop
            int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight; 

            // By now we got the height of titleBar & statusBar , Now lets get the screen size
            int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;

            // Now calculate the height that our layout can be set If you know that your application doesn't have statusBar added, then don't add here also. 
            //Same applies to application bar also
            int layoutHeight = screenHeight - (titleBarHeight + statusBarHeight);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`display.getRealSize(size);` instead of `display.getSize(size);`

source:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)

Answer (score 0):

you can use DisplayMetrics. This class holds information about the screen such its size, density, font scaling. For instance

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels
```

returns

```
The absolute width of the display in pixels.
```

to retrieve the height

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method of your class write down this code, and you will get the actual width and height of screen:

Display mDisplay = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

```
    final int width = mDisplay.getWidth();

    final int height = mDisplay.getHeight();

    System.out.println("width " + width + "  height " + height);
```